# sh to read a file and take particular value in shell

Tags: shell

I need to read a json file and take value like `99XXXXXXXXXXXX0` and `cccs` and write in csv which having column `BASE_No` and `Schedule`.

Input file: classedFFDCD_5666_4888_45_2018_02112018012106.021.json

```
"bfgft":"99XXXXXXXXXXXX0","fp":"XXXXXX","cur_gt":225XXXXXXXX0,"cccs"
"bfgft":"21XXXXXXXXXXXX0","fp":"XXXXXX","cur_gt":225XXXXXXXX0,"nncs"
"bfgft":"56XXXXXXXXXXXX0","fp":"XXXXXX","cur_gt":225XXXXXXXX0,"fgbs"
"bfgft":"44XXXXXXXXXXXX0","fp":"XXXXXX","cur_gt":225XXXXXXXX0,"ddss"
"bfgft":"94XXXXXXXXXXXX0","fp":"XXXXXX","cur_gt":225XXXXXXXX0,"jjjs"
```

Expected output:

```
BASE_No,Schedule
99XXXXXXXXXXXX0,cccs
21XXXXXXXXXXXX0,nncs
56XXXXXXXXXXXX0,fgbs
44XXXXXXXXXXXX0,ddss
94XXXXXXXXXXXX0,jjjs
```

I am using below code for reading file name and date, but unable to read file for `BASE_No`,`Schedule`.

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for line in `ls -lrt *.json`; do
        date=$(echo $line |awk -F ' ' '{print $6" "$7}');
        file=$(echo $line |awk -F ' ' '{print $9}');
        echo ''$file','$(date "+%Y/%m/%d  %H.%M.%S")'' >> $File_Tracker`
```

Comment: It would be easier to parse the file with JSON aware parser if this one had valid JSON data. Are you sure the file contains valid JSON data? If so, please update your question.

Comment: so the input file exaclty in the format above? Why does code need to interate all .json files ? Or do you have a a number files, and want to get the data from each ?

Comment: Yes, i want to data from each file, hence writen *.json.

Comment: Is that all your code ? What did you try so far to get your expected output ?

Comment: I have tried below code which work for "99XXXXXXXXXXXX0" but unable to "cccs"   >> code>>awk 'BEGIN { FS="\""; RS="," }; { if ($2 == "gstin") {print $4} }' classedFFDCD_5666_4888_45_2018_02112018012106.021.json

Comment: Currently i have written the code to write file name and date in csv, now i need this two value 99XXXXXXXXXXXX0 and cccs from json and write recursively along with file name and date

Comment: Can any one help me? please

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of the json doesnt change for every line, the sample code checks through line by line to retrieve the particular value and concatenates using `printf`. The output is then stored as new `output.txt` file.

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/home/kj4458/winhome/Downloads/sample.json"
printf "Base,Schedule \n" > output.txt
while IFS= read -r var
do
        printf "`echo "$var" | cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d',' -f 1`,`echo "$var" | cut -d':' -f 4 | cut -d',' -f 2` \n" | sed 's/"//g' >> output.txt
  done < "$input"
```

Comment: i am getting below output. Base,Schedule . value is not populating

Comment: while running manually printf "`echo "$var" | cut -d':' -f 2 | cut -d',' -f 1`,`echo "$var" | cut -d':' -f 4 | cut -d',' -f 2` \n" | sed 's/"//g' >> output.txt, then it is working but not working in loop

Comment: @user1376290 did you change specify the input file with the correct path. Can you put these lines in `input.sh` and run it using `sh input.sh`. I am pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Yes I have change the specify path and I have run with sh and even I have run with single command in Linux. It doesn't work. When I have run printf with var command it gives correct output but while running in sh it doesn't work

Comment: did you add this `#!/bin/bash` in your first line? its very strange why it doesnt run. I suspect it to be indentation problem while copying it.

Comment: Even with entering bash it is giving only header not the output line.  Also when running printf line manually it is working

Comment: @user1376290: Can you check the indentation after `do`. Can you make sure they are spaced the way they are supposed to?

Answer (score 0):

**awk -F " \" "   ' {print  $4","$12 }'   file**

99XXXXXXXXXXXX0,cccs

21XXXXXXXXXXXX0,nncs

56XXXXXXXXXXXX0,fgbs

44XXXXXXXXXXXX0,ddss

94XXXXXXXXXXXX0,jjjs

I got that result!

Comment: While running below scripts, i am getting output only ","

Comment: with the example of the file that passed I had this result ! Are you using awk alone? or together with another command?